# How To Find Related Record ID Based Reference Document No on SQL Statement

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, relationship

I need to show related record id based document no as reference in same table. I try many time and direction but cannot get a right output.

This below are table and data:

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aBE.png)

Basically Record ID no 2,4 and 10 are related based on Reference Document No. For example if I select record id no 4 I still can list all related document from first to last transaction.

I hope someone who cross this problem or anybody have a solution from SQL Statement or coding on .net please as long I can show this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using postgres, since this is tagged with it.  You can make a recursive query that will accomplish what you want when you're querying for a given docno:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT docno, refdocno
    FROM <table>
    WHERE docno = 'T0003'

    UNION

    SELECT blah.docno, blah.refdocno
    FROM <table>
    JOIN t ON t.docno    = blah.refdocno
           OR t.refdocno = blah.docno
)
SELECT *
  FROM t;
```

Note: you'll have to put the docno you're searching for in the with statement.  If you need other columns, you can put them in there as well.

PS. I assume that row 10's refdocno was supposed to be T0003 in your example

Comment: Hello,

Thanks you very much Spasticmonkey and Ramfjord to pointing me what should I do and learning from you two.

I suppose change my title to How To Find Related Record ID Based Reference Document No on Same Table. Maybe after this.

"PS. I assume that row 10's refdocno was supposed to be T0003 in your example"

You are correct Ramfjord, that my mistake on picture I attach. Sorry.

I will try both solutions from yours guy and let your know the result.
Anyway thanks you for your time to show a solutions and explanation on that. 

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to link all documents on the parent document? If you wanted to, say get a document and find all related documents for docno XY001 (assuming XY001 is the parent Document otherwise link the other way around)
You could use

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS parentDoc
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS referentialDoc ON parentDoc.docno = referentialDoc.refdocno
WHERE parentDoc.docno = XY001
```

Of Course you can change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE referentialDoc.docno IS NOT NULL
```

to show only those with a referential document.

also note that this is only good for a structure of parent - child. for structure of grandparent-parent-child and more, you will need to either expand the Query or do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

After try Ramfjord solution I got a result what I want. I just add a little touch to sequence my result where I can see from first until last transactions like below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
SELECT **recid**, docno, refdocno
FROM <table>
WHERE docno = 'T0003'

UNION

SELECT **c.recid**, docno, refdocno
FROM <table> c
JOIN t ON t.docno = c.refdocno
       OR t.refdocno = c.docno
)
SELECT *
    FROM t **order by recid**;
```

Ramfjord you already save my day!

Spasticmonkey your solutions also good for Parent-Child table. I will use your solution for other task.